# Why do I lose my QList items when accessing it in another function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qlist

[GraphWidget Timeline Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbc97.png)

I have a list called node1List which stores a list of nodes that are to be displayed in a QGraphicsScene. GraphWidget.cpp is a timeline where the user can click to add nodes. EffectsWidget is another timeline which has the option to add three QLabels to the scene. When these labels are added, I need to add a node to the graphWidget timeline in the same respective place.

list declaration in `graphWidget.h`:

```
private:
QList<Node *> node1List;
```

In graphWidget.cpp, on Mouse Click I create a node and add it to the list:

```
void GraphWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->button()) {
    case Qt::MouseButton::RightButton: {
        //... create node
        addNode1(newNode, location);
        //...
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

Here is the addNode1 function which is declared in the same graphWidget.cpp:

```
void GraphWidget::addNode1(Node *newNode,int  loc)
{
    node1List.insert(loc, newNode);
}
```

This all works fine and I can access the list of nodes WITHIN the mouse press event.

However now I need to allow these nodes to be also added when a label is added to another class, effectsWidget.cpp.

```
void EffectsWidget::addEffectsItemStart(){
    graphWidget = new GraphWidget();
    graphWidget->addLabelsToListAt(sceneStartLabel, 1);
    //...
}
```

and then

```
void GraphWidget::addLabelsToListAt(QLabel *label, int location)
{
    labelListGraphWidget.insert(location, label);
    generateNodes(label);
}
```

So finally, now when I call `generateNodes(label)`, I output the size of the `node1List` only to find that it is empty?

```
void GraphWidget::generateNodes(QLabel* label)
{
    //The following outputs zero
    DBOUT("List size = " << node1List.size() << "\n");

    //...create new node

    addNode1(newNode, location);
}
```

If anyone could please explain to me how to retain all the items in a list it would be great thanks! First question here so my apologies if I've messed it up!

Comment: We need to see a [mcve]. You might be calling the functions on different `GraphWidget` objects, but we can't tell without seeing all the (and *only the*) relevant code.

Comment: You actually helped me fix it right there. I was messy in creating my `GraphWidget`objects, so instead of calling my functions in a loop I went back to my main program and called the `generateNodes()`function from there. Thanks a lot for your time